# How do I add/request microphone permission to Java app that runs on MacOS Mojave 10.14?

Tags: java, macos, permissions, microphone, macos-mojave

According to the new privacy feature of MacOS Mojave 10.14 that needs to confirm permission to use microphone on apps, My Java app (runnable jar) is not recording sound at all when it is running not from a Terminal or Eclipse.

How can I add/request microphone permission directly from the java app?

Runs on Java 8 update 221.

Comment: Hi did you find solution? I am badly stuck on the same problem. I got two systems Mac OS Catalina. Java doesn't ask permission on both systems. However on one system I am able to access Microphone and able to record while on another it is not able to detect sound in mic. Please share if you got solution.

Comment: I updated my Mac OS to Catalina 10.15.2 and my Java version to 8.231 and now when I am running .jar file with request microphone permission the OS ask me about mic permission and "java" added to my microphone "Privacy" in "System Preferences".

Comment: I stuck upon this for long time. Finally here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60648164/1911652