# Java app does not request permissions to use the microphone (MacOs Big Sur)

Tags: java, macos, api, audio

I wrote an app which is supposed to detect the level of the microphone volume. However, it doesn't detect anything. I think it's because it doesn't have the permissions to use the microphone. Is there any way to force my app to ask for the permission?

The IDE I use is NetBeans and JDK v16.

Comment: i've seen this problem was resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727488/application-doesnt-ask-for-permission-to-access-microphone-in-macos-10-14-mojav/60648164#60648164

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.